# Google Maps and WCAG 2.0 level A

Tags: google-maps, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

I have a map that displays custom markers with filtering options and different markers colors based on the filtering options. Clicking a marker displays a text bubble with a picture as expected.

What is required to make a google map comply with level A. Obviously a screen reader version will be far less exciting.

[WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/)

What do I need to do to make my google map comply with WCAG 2.0 level A?

**EDIT:**

I think I need a solution for:

1.1 TEXT ALTERNATIVES

-Map has hundreds of markers, and not accessible because they exist as js objects

1.3 ADAPTABLE

-It's not possible to detect a screen reader and adapt accordingly

2.1 KEYBOARD ACCESSIBLE

-Google maps does not provide hot-keys although I'm sure it's possible to wire some up with js.

4.1 COMPATIBLE

-This would rule out any js hacks to make google maps respond to hotkeys.

**What's best practice?**
What about linking to a list of my markers as text via an accessible version link?

Comment: Although not google maps related, have a look at how OpenStreetMap deals with this matter http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Accessibility. I'm also evaluating how I can make my web mapping application comply with the WCAG standards, so interested in seeing what others have to say on this.

Comment: An interesting document but not quite an answer to my question. This is more about actually providing maps catered to disabled people based on their disability. I'm only delivering stories via markers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution for this is going to be:

- Treat the map like video/media content
- Provide a text list similar to what's being displayed on the map on an alternate page. With the link clearly labeled as the accessible version.
- Provide a description of what the map is trying to achieve.

This is a section of the WCAG 2.0 that talks about linking to accessible versions:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20130905/G73

Someone is trying to solve a similar problem here:

http://www.accessifyforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=23294